# Stop "View Image" links going to a Google url before redirecting

Tags: google-image-search

When I click "View Image" in Google images results I get sent to a Google page which redirects me to the image.

How do I change this so I go straight to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search for an image, instead of clicking on View Image - just right click on the image you see and select `"Open Image in New Tab"`

Should work!

Comment: Yes you're right. Oftentimes I just want the url though, so I'd click `Copy image address`